# Can you use ConfigureAwait(false) without being thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core, thread-safety

I see people all over the place recommend using `ConfigureAwait(false)` where you can, and it is a must for library authors, and so on.

But since the continuation of `ConfigureAwait(false)` can run on any thread from thread pool, then how can you safely protect against multiple threads accessing the same state in your library?

Say you have the following API for your library:

```
async Task FooAsync()
{
    // Do something
    
    //barAsync and saveToFileAsync are private methods.
    await barAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    // counter is a private field
    counter++;

    await saveToFileAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    // Do other things
}
```

If a UI thread keeps calling this `FooAsync` (e.g. because of user pressing button), wouldn't this code corrupt the value of `counter` and the file saved? Since multiple threads might be executing?

I find it hard to fanthom using `ConfigureAwait(false)` without being thread-safe, except for the simplist cases that do not modify state.

## Update

I might not have been clear, but in our team, we decided we are going single-threaded. And so, from the answers below, it seems we can't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` then, since it introduces the possibility of parallelism, which needs to be controlled using locks and so on.

Comment: You can't. Not sure what else to say. Your code is not thread-safe even without the use of ConfigureAwait, for that context, because you have no guarantee that the caller is on the UI thread in the first place.

Comment: You'd probably need to look into locking at that point

Comment: The recommendation is to use ConfigureAwait(false) as long as the code is not context-aware. An example being HttpContext in a asp .NET application. You cannot access that from threads other than the request thread.

Comment: @Lasse You are right. Most people don't design for thread-safety, and they think that there is only one thread running which is the default. Normal async/await fits nicely with this, however, the moment you add ConfigureAwait(false), then you need thread-safety, but no body seems to address this in most questions I visited, and it gives the impression that ConfigureAwait(false) is a simple change, but no, it has consequenses and might result in corrupted state.

Comment: `Most people don't design for thread-safety` I don't think that is really true. Most *good* libraries are thread-safe simply because the little global state that exists is locked against. There is no expectation that a single object should be thread-safe unless stated specifically (such as `Concurrent...` classes). For example, `List<T>` is not thread-safe as a single object. `SqlConnection` is not thread-safe, but uses an internal connection pool which is.

Comment: @Charlieface It is an internal library for a mobile app, not for public. You can see the update, thanks.

Comment: As I said: parallelism and thread-safety is not really the point. The key is to avoid global state as much as possible, that way you don't need to think about locking.

Comment: @Charlieface You cannot avoid all global state, yes you can reduce it, but you cannot eliminate it (I am talking here about private fields, not globally visible fields across objects). In that case, `ConfigureAwait(false)` is problematic if one does not pay attention. It is not a simple change.

Comment: I don't get it: if they are private fields why do you need to lock? Why use an object across different threads if you don't have to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But since the continuation of ConfigureAwait(false) can run on any thread from thread pool, then how can you safely protect against multiple threads accessing the same state in your library?

`await` does introduce the possibility of reentrancy, but having it actually cause a problem is rare. Asynchronous code by its nature encourages a more functional kind of structure (inputs to a method are its parameters, and outputs are its return values). It's *possible* to have asynchronous methods have side effects and depend on state, but it's not terribly common.

Note that it is the `await` that causes accidental reentrancy. `ConfigureAwait(false)` resumes on the thread pool, but that doesn't cause the issue here.

> If a UI thread keeps calling this FooAsync (e.g. because of user pressing button), wouldn't this code corrupt the value of counter and the file saved? Since multiple threads might be executing?

Yes and sort of. Yes, the counter may get an unexpected value, but it's not necessarily because of multiple threads. Consider the same code without `ConfigureAwait(false)`: you still have multiple invocations of that function running, just on a single thread. They're still fighting over the counter and any other shared state. In that case, because of the single thread, `counter++` is atomic, but because it's shared, a single invocation of that function may see the value unexpectedly change when resuming from an `await`.

With `ConfigureAwait(false)`, you *do* have the additional concern of accidental *parallelism* (with `await` you have accidental *reentrancy*), so if you have non-threadsafe shared state, things can get worse. Reentrancy can cause unexpected states, but parallelism can cause invalid states.

Answer (score 2):

`ConfigureAwait` is not about thread-safety. It's about avoiding capturing the context.

If you want your code to be thread-safe, then you should implement it to be. This usually involves using some kind of synchronization construct(s), such as for example a lock.

As already pointed out, your `FooAsync()` is *not* thread-safe even if you remove the calls to `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Two or more threads can still call it simultaneously, even in a UI application where there is a `SynchronizationContext` available.

> how can you safely protect against multiple threads accessing the same state in your library?

By synchronizing the access to any shared resource. Assuming `counter` is the only critical section in your code, you could make the method thread-safe using the `Interlocked.Increment` API:

```
async Task FooAsync()
{
    ...
    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    ...
}
```

This will increment `counter` and store the new result as an atomic operation.

There are a bunch of other synchronization constructs as well. Which one to use depends on what you are doing basically. Avoid calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not a way to make code thread-safe though.

Comment: Thanks, @mm8. I think I might not have been clear. If in our team we decided we are going single threaded, then `ConfigureAwait(false)` seems to break this role. As for `FooAsync()` it is guaranteed is going to be called from UI thread.